# javascript codes are not responding properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am trying calculate the amount but having troble with jQuery .. can you guys please tell me whats wrong with my codes.

my Javascript and jQuery codes are:

i have change this as:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.home_banner').cycle({
        fx: 'fade'
    });
    $("#tabs").tabs();
});
```

and calculator codes as:

```
var u_rate   = new Array();
    u_rate[0]    = new Array();
    u_rate[0][0] = 1.022;
    u_rate[0][1] = 0.75; 

    u_rate[1]    = new Array();
    u_rate[1][0] = 1.034;
    u_rate[1][1] = 0.78;

calc();

function calc(){
    var result = '';
    var id = '';
        id = 'u'; 
        curr = u_rate;
    var curin_id = jquery("#"+id+"currency_in").attr("selectedIndex");
    var curout_id = jquery("#"+id+"currency_out").attr("selectedIndex");

    var value_float = parseFloat(jquery("#"+id+"value").val());

    if(value_float>0){
        result=value_float*curr[curin_id][curout_id];
        result=Math.round(result*100)/100;
    }
    jquery("#"+id+"result").val(result);
    return true;
}
```

but still getting no response .. please check this and let me know

and the html is

please check on [ukash2gold.com](http://ukash2gold.com)

please friends let me know how to resolve the issue ..

u will able to see the form under the tab of [Ukash to LR]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`typeof jQuery` yields `"function"` but `typeof $` yields `"undefined"`. Are you loading jQuery in noConflict mode?

---

**Edit 1**

Yes you are; your slideshow code starts off like this:

```
var $jnav=jQuery.noConflict();
```

See [noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).

---

**Edit 2**

As far as I can tell, you're not using any other framework that uses the `$` variable. In that case, you can safely remove noConflict from your slideshow:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.home_banner').cycle({
        fx: 'fade' // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
    });
    $("#tabs").tabs();
});
</script>
```

If you're using another framework somewhere else on the site, and need to stick to running jQuery in noConflict mode, you'll have to modify your jQuery code to use `jQuery` rather than the `$` shorthand.

```
jQuery('#'+id+'result').val(result);
```

... etc.

---

**Edit 3**

Now you're seeing the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined` at this line:

```
result=value_float*curr[curin_id][curout_id];
```

What this means is, in your case, that `curin_id` and `curout_id` are both undefined. Therefore you're trying to access a property `'undefined'` (`curout_id`) at the object `'undefined'` (`curr[curin_id]` which will yield `undefined` since `curin_id` is in itself `undefined`).

The cause for this is the following code:

```
var curin_id = $("#"+id+"currency_in").attr("selectedIndex");
var curout_id = $("#"+id+"currency_out").attr("selectedIndex");
```

`selectedIndex` is not an *attribute* of the `select` but a *property* of it. Although properties are native JavaScript constructions, you can read about them in [the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

A simple fix in your case would be to change from `attr()` to `prop()`:

```
var curin_id = $("#"+id+"currency_in").prop("selectedIndex");
var curout_id = $("#"+id+"currency_out").prop("selectedIndex");
```

Another solution would be to look at the *index* of the selected element, within its parent:

```
var curin_id = $('#'+id+'currency_in option:selected').index();
```

Comment: can you give me some codes idea .. what to do .. i m not so good with jQuery

Comment: please check i have edited the codes as well as but its not responding. @David Hedlund